# How to move/shift around several rows in V-line mode using vim. Lines are 2 rows apart

Tags: vim

For example, I want to select lines starting with B28, B29 and B30 using Shift + v  in row B28 , then select row B29 and so on..., then press 'd' and then move to ROW 1 and press 'Shift-p' in the first row to paste all these rows there.

```
ROW 1 

A26       51.00824   
D26       35.94841  
D27       35.94841  
B28        7.07486  
A28       35.95497  
D28      179.99932  
B29        4.15400  
A29       90.00068  
D29      179.99932  
B30        7.07490
```

Answer (score 1):

Visual mode(s) can only select contiguous regions (this applies to characterwise, linewise, and blockwise visual mode, regardless of the value of `virtualedit`). The only exception is ragged line-endings with, say, `vip$`.

But you can accomplish your goal other ways. For example:

```
:global/^B\d+/move /ROW 1/-
```

Should move all lines starting with `B` followed by digits to the line after `ROW 1`. (They will probably be reversed; in your case, a simple `:sort n` will probably be do, but generally `:[range]!tac` or `:[range]global/./move <firstline>` can reverse lines.)

Or, you could record a macro like so:

- Mark insertion point: `:/ROW 1/mark a`
- start a recursive macro in register `q`: `qqqq` (the first three clear the register)
- go to next occurence to move `/^B\d+`
- move it `dd'ap`
- adjust mark `ma`
- recursive invocation `@q`
- fini `q`

Now hit `@q` and watch the magic.

If you needed to repeat the above many times for different things, I would write a series of commands to get it working once, then turn that into a function and generalize the things that are variable. Voilà, automation.

Comment: I've tried `…move /ROW 1/;'}` but that doesn't work, for some reason

Answer (score 1):

Another method, just for fun:

```
:g/^B/normal! dd1G}P
```

- `:g/^B/<cmd>` executes `<cmd>` on every line starting with a `B`,
- `normal! <macro>` executes normal mode macro `<macro>`,
- `dd` cuts the line to the unnamed register,
- `1G` moves the cursor to line 1,
- `}` moves the cursor to the empty line after the current paragraph, this is key because it allows us to put the next line below the last one that was put and thus to respect order,
- `P` puts the content of the unnamed register above the current line.

Reference:

```
:help :global
:help :normal
:help /^
:help dd
:help G
:help }
:help P
```

--- EDIT ---

There are plenty of ways to address your target, even if it is not on line 1.

- With a line number:

  ```
  :g/^B/normal! dd23G}P
  ```
- With a mark:

  ```
  ma
  :g/^B/normal! dd'a}P
  ```
- With a search:

  ```
  :g/^B/normal! dd?ROW1^M}P    " ^M is obtained with <C-v><CR>
  ```

Comment: This solution worked great, knowing the line number of 'ROW 1' match (if it is in a different place in your file and not at the beginning of it) you can substitute `1G`  for linenumber`G` and get the lines pasted there.